# Determining set and Automorphism group of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group, infinite-graphs

Let $G$ be a simple graph. A set $S\subset V(G)$ is said to be determining set of $G$, if for any two Automorphisms $f,g \in Aut(G)$ whenever $f(s)=g(s)$ for all $s\in S$, then  $f=g$. That is, an automorphism can be determined by its images in $S$.

If $G$ is an infinite graph and $Aut(G)$ is infinite. Can $G$ have a finite determining set.
 If possible find a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at the infinite graph $G$ such that $V(G)=\mathbb{N}$, $E(G)=\{(n,n+1)|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.
It's clear that $G$ does not have any non-trivial automorphisms.
Now we can take infinitely many copies of this graph, namely the graph $G=(V^{'},E^{'})$ with $V^{'}=\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N},E=\{((i,j), (i,j+1)|i,j\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
As we don't have non-trivial automorphisms inside any connectivity component, we have that the automorphisms are exactly permutations that permute the connectivity classes while keeping them intact, and so $\text{Aut}(G)\cong S_{\mathbb{N}}$ where $S_X$ is the group of all permutations on $X$.

But, it doesn't seem like it helps much, as we just said that the automorphisms are just like permutations of $\mathbb{N}$, we can't reconstruct a permutation by the images of any finite set.

So, let's add the vertices $V^{''}=\{v_{\sigma} |\sigma\in S_{\mathbb{N}}\}$ and $E^{''}=\{(v_{\sigma}, (i,j)) |v_\sigma\in V^{''}, j\le\sigma^{-1}(i) \}$.
Basically, what we do here is add a new vertex to correspond to each permutation on $\mathbb{N}$, and for each such vertex we order the connectivty components (by $\sigma(1),\sigma(2),...$) and connected this vertex to the $i$'th components with $i$ links, where the links go to the "first" vertices in the connectivity class.

Now we have a problem, as we made the graph **way** more complex, and we may have just introducted many more automorphisms, so we need to fix that.

Intoduce the (last) $V^{'''},E^{'''}$ such that $V^{'''}=\{u,u^{'}\}, E^{'''}=\{(u,u^{'})\}\cup\{(u,v)|v\in V^{''}\}$. So we created a new vertex and connected it to all of the $v_\sigma$'s and then yet a new vertex to connect to that vertex.

Finally, define $G=(V,E)$ where $V=V^{'}\cup V^{''} \cup V^{'''}, E=E^{'}\cup E^{''} \cup E^{'''}$.

Now, let $\psi$ be an automorphism of $G$. as $u^{'}$ is the only vertex of degree $1$, $\psi(u^{'})=u^{'}$, and thus also $\psi(u)=u$.
As $N(u)=V^{''}$, $\psi[N(\psi(u)]=V^{''}\rightarrow\psi[V^{''}]=V^{''}$ and we got that $$w\in V^{''}\leftrightarrow \psi(w)\in V^{''},w\in V^{'} \leftrightarrow \psi(w)\in V^{'}$$

Now it should be easy to see that $\psi$ again permutes connectivity classes - indeed, if $\psi(i,1)=(i^{'},j)$ such that $j > 1$ , then $\psi(i,1)$ has $2$ neightbors in $V^{'}$ but from the property we have established, it means $(i,1)$ has $2$ neightbors in $V^{'}$ which is not true, so $\psi(i,1)=\psi(i^{'},1)$ for some $i^{'}\in \mathbb{N}$ and it easily follows by induction that $\psi(i,j)=\psi(i^{'},j^{'})\rightarrow j=j^{'}$.

So we got that every automorphism permutes connectivity classes, so if we will look at the automorphisms reduced to the domain $V^{'}$, we will get a group that is $\cong S_\mathbb{N}$, as we have mentioned at the start.

Let $\sigma \in S_\mathbb{N}$, and $\psi$ the corresponding automorphism, and let's see how it can be extended to an automorphism on $G$.

As the number of links from $v_\phi \in V^{''}$ to $G_i$ (where $G_i$ is the subgraph of $(V^{'},E^{'})$ by taking only the vertices $\{(i,j)|j\in \mathbb{N} \}$) must be the same as the number of links between $\psi(v_\phi)$ and $G_{\sigma(i)}$ we are left no choice but to set $\psi(v_\phi)=v_{\sigma \circ \phi}$.

We got that again $\text{Aut}(G)\cong S_\mathbb{N}$, and notice that the automorphism matching to $\sigma \in S_\mathbb{N}$, $\psi$, maps $v_{id}$ to $v_\sigma$. That is, every automorphism of $G$, can be represneted uniquely by a $\sigma \in S_\mathbb{N}$, and the vertex $v_{id} \in V^{''} \subset V$ has the unique image $v_\sigma$.
So, by the definition of determining sets, $S=\{v_{id}\}$ is a determining set of $G$.  $$\square$$

Note:
The argument below works for every vertex $v_\sigma \in V^{''}$, so we actually got **infinitely many** determining sets of size $1$.

Comment: Sir, in the statement, "components (by σ(1),σ(2),...) and connected this vertex to the i'th components with i links,", it should be j-links instead of i links. am I correct sir.